# how to validate the input parameters before using in the static query?? SQL server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005

consider table1 with 2 columns..

```
table1: 
 column1 int,
 column2 char
```

```
create procedure SP1(@col1,@col2) as
begin
    select * from table1 where _______ 
end
```

Question: User may enter valid input for either (col1 or col2) or (both col1 and col2).so i need to validate the user input and use those correct column(s) in the satic query.

eg: if both inputs are correct then, the query will be:

```
select * from table1 where column1=@col1 and column2 =@col2
```

if only col2 is valid and col1 is not a valida one, then this:

```
select * from table1 where column2=@col2
```

how to validate the input parameters before using in the static query??  in sql server 2005

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like:

```
Create Procedure Sp1( @Col1..., @Col2... )
As

-- if @Col1 is not valid, then set it to Null
If @Col1 <> <valid number or string or date> 
    Set @Col1 = Null

-- if @Col2 is not valid, then set it to Null
If @Col2 <> <valid number or string or date>
    Set @Col2 = Null

Select ...
From Table1
Where ( @Col1 Is Not Null Or @Col2 Is Not Null )
    And ( Col1 = @Col1 Or @Col1 Is Null )
    And ( Col2 = @Col2 Or @Col2 Is Null )
```

Comment: I came up with the same thing.  Deleted mine.  +1 to you.

Comment: thanks for the reply..yes similar to this..can u pls tel me how to  validate the column before using??

Comment: this method will not use an index, and will run slow if large tables are involved.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
Create Procedure Sp1( @Col1..., @Col2... )
As

If @Col1 {is valid} AND @Col2 {is valid} 
BEGIN
    select * from dbo.table1 where column1=@col1 and column2 =@col2
END
ELSE @Col2 {is valid} 
BEGIN
    select * from dbo.table1 where column2=@col2 
END

RETURN 0
GO
```

be careful using the (@col1 IS NULL or @Col1=Col1) trick, an index will not be used.  Read [Dynamic Search Conditions in T-SQL by Erland Sommarskog](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2005.html) to see all the PROs and CONs of each dynamic search method.  I chose the [If method](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2005.html#IF) because the OP only lists 2 conditions to search on, so it would seem feasible to do it this way.

Comment: thanks.. but i don want to repeat the query again and again..because, my query having 'n' number of lines.

Comment: @Guru, you don't give enough details about your query, but read the article I link to.  There are many considerations to making the query preform well.

Answer (score 0):

In such case it looks like dynamic SQL will be the best option - you will generate the WHERE clause depending on the validity of arguments and then execute the whole query with sp_executesql